# Sim900a AT+HTTPREAD does not get fully answer

Tags: arduino-nano, gsm, http

changed the firmware on SIM900B

try to send get request http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/1
`AT+HTTPACTION=0`returned `+HTTPACTION:0,200,98`

but, when I try to read (`AT+HTTPREAD` or `AT+HTTPREAD=0,98`)the response data
I got broken response

expected result:

```
+HTTPREAD:98
{"id":"1","employee_name":"Shibani","employee_salary":"999","employee_age":"0","profile_image":""}
```

and actual results:

```
+HTTPREAD:98
{"id":"1","employee_name":"Shibani","employee_salary":"999","empe_"0"olme"

+HTTPREAD:98
{"id":"1","employee_name":"Shibani","employee_salary":"999","empe_"0"fea"}

+HTTPREAD:98
{"id":"1","employee_name":"Shibani","employee_salary":"999""pea:,piig"

+HTTPREAD:98
{"id":"1","employee_name":"Shibani","employee_salary":"999",moeg""reae}
```

my Arduino code looks like that

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(57600);
  delay(5000);
  mySerial.println("AT");
  Serial.println("End of the setup");
}

void loop() {
  if (mySerial.available())
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
  if (Serial.available())
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());
}
```

Comment: Edit the question : post your arduino code.  Looks like a string overflow might be happening.

Comment: Maybe you're doing that silly "wait 5 seconds and assume there's a reply" thing I see all over the place. Or maybe you're using SoftwareSerial at 115200 baud...  No one can know - unless you share your code...

Comment: @Majenko, thanks, I've changed the baud to 9600 and it started work fine

Comment: @Majenko After doing 
mySerial.println("AT+HTTPACTION=0");
mySerial.println("AT+HTTPREAD"); 
delay(1000);  //how do i get response without waiting a specific time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you were running software serial at too high of a baud rate (57600) and bringing it down to 9600 fixed the issue.